# Passing a constructor to array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have always been using vectors for storing objects when a list type container is required.
I wanted to know how you can pass constructors to array pointers.The following works in     C++03 if the object foo did not have a constructor

```
foo* p = new foo[5]()
```

Now what if the constructor of `foo` required an `int` how would I pass the constructor in the above statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, you can use brace initializers:

```
foo * p = new foo[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };   // better: "auto p = ..."
```

This assumes that `foo` is *implicitly* constructible from `int`.

But you can just as well use containers:

```
std::vector<foo> v { 1, 2, 3 };
std::list<foo> w { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Or perhaps:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo[]> q(new foo[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4} );
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Your `foo` instances can only be default-constructed.

**UPDATE 1**

If your `foo` does not have a default constructor then you will get a compiler error either about use of deleted function or about no matching ctor.

**UPDATE 2**

I see that others offer C++11 solution. My answer appears to be correct only for C++03 or earlier.

Comment: what if `foo` does not have a default constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

> how would I pass the constructor in the above statement?

`new[]` does not have a form for forwarding constructor parameters.

You would instead call the constructors yourself.

```
foo* p = new foo[5]{ foo(1), foo(2), foo(3), foo(4), foo(5) };
```

Comment: `foo* p = new foo[5]{ foo(1), foo(2), foo(3), foo(4), foo(5) };` does not work. It states '`no default constructor exists for class `foo`

Comment: @Casper_2211 I recommend editing your question to mention that you are using C++03, not C++11.